# rotate verticies es2

Tags: opengl-es-2.0

how do i rotate verticies in opengl es2

in es1 i can just do 
glRotatef(transY, 0, 0, 1);

however under  es2 it crashes

is the same thing possible in es2

using iphone sdk for xcode

Answer (score 0):

In OpenGL ES2 the `glRotatef()` function no longer exists.  Instead I believe you need to use a vertex shader to accomplish the desired translation.  The following resources may be helpful:

[OpenGL ES2 API Documentation](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/)
[Shader Tutorial](http://mobileorchard.com/getting-started-with-opengl-es-20-on-the-iphone-3gs/)